# UV and 3 or 4 Dimensional point

Tags: python, scripting, uv, dimensions

in shader programming it's possible to use the w and z dimension of the uv coordinate to. Basically, uv coordinates are in shader an 4 dimensional value. But the last two dimensions are won't be used in the normal case.

I want to use this extra dimensions of an uv coordinate to store some extra information in it.

Now my questions:
Is that possible via an pythonscript in Blender?
And does the fbx export tool support this too?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No.  But you could combine 2 UV maps and read the second as z and w if you want.  Or you could use a vertex group to store some extra information.  Which is kind of what they're for.